# Equivariant Homotopy

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, equivariant-homotopy

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ be $\{\pm1\}$ and let there be two $G$-spaces given: $X=$ The surface of a cylinder *including* its boundary circles and $S^4$. That means we two G-actions $f_1:G\times X\to X$ and $f_2:G\times S^4 \to S^4$. Imagine that $f_2$ is actually a family of $G$-actions on $S^4$ parametrized by $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, and each member is denoted $f_2^j$ where $j\in\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\equiv\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

For fixed $j$, how do you go about classifying all $G$-maps from $X\to S^4$ up to $G$-equivariant homotopies?

---

I've been reading about equivariant homotopy but it seems like an overkill for the $G$ and two spaces I have in mind. There must be a more simple approach.

---

If it helps, I can specify $f_1$ and $f_2$:

The cylinder is given by $X=\{(z,\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2|z\in\left[0,1\right]\land\theta\in\left[-\pi,\pi\right]\}/\{(z,\pi) \tilde{} (z,-\pi)\}$.

Then $$(-1, (0,\theta)) \stackrel{f_1}{\mapsto}(0,-\theta)$$ $$(-1, (1,\theta)) \stackrel{f_1}{\mapsto}(1,-\theta)$$ $$(-1, (z,\theta)) \stackrel{f_1}{\mapsto}(z,\theta)\,\,\,\forall z\in\left(0,1\right)$$

If $S^4\equiv \{x\in\mathbb{R}^5|\,\,\,x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2+x_5^2=1\}$  then $$ \left(-1,\left(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5\right)\right)\stackrel{f_2^j}{\mapsto} \left((-1)^{H(j)})x_1, (-1)^{H(j-1)}x_2, (-1)^{H(j-2)}x_3, (-1)^{H(j-3)}x_4, x_5\right) $$ 
where $H(j) = 1$ if $j\geq1$ and $H(j) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: Since you can $G$-equivariantly retract the cylinder to a circle, I don't see the point in including the $z$ coordinate. (I also don't see why you've split up the definition of $f_1$ into three lines, instead of just $(-1,(z,\theta))\mapsto (z,-\theta) \forall z$.)

Comment: @AllenKnutson, thanks for your comment. It appears I made a mistake in the formulation of $f_1$ and so I have edited my question to fix it. I hope now it makes more sense that I have defined $f_1$ in three (or two if you will) lines. Since you have two circles at the boundaries of $X$, I wasn't sure if I could retract the cylinder into one circle or two, and if I retract it into two circles, what are the conditions between the two circles then, if any.

Comment: Now your $f_1$ isn't continuous.

Comment: Perhaps equivariant homotopy is unrelated to this problem. Is there a way to relax the continuity condition on the group action? But still define a $G$-map $f:X\to S^4$ to be a map such that $f(f_1(g, (z,\theta))) = f_2(g, f(z, \theta))$.

Comment: Is $\ X := S^1\times[0;1]$ ?

Comment: I guess you don't have group actions, just spaces with equivalence relations on them? In particular $X/\sim$ is $S^2$ with two cross-caps?

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński, yes, it is, I just wrote the parametrization explicitly to specify $f_1$. AllenKnutson, are you saying X/~ is the Klein-bottle? I don't see that.. I'm also unsure how you get from $G$-maps to quotient spaces.

Comment: (1) Start with a cylinder including its boundary _discs_, so, $S^2$. Cutting out an open disc and $Z_2$-identifying its boundary circle is the same as gluing in a cross-cap; that's what you're doing at top and bottom of your cylindrical $S^2$. (2) An equivariant map $X\to Y$ induces a map $X/G\to Y/G$. (But not vice versa: consider $X=Y=Z_2$, with two equivariant maps that become the same in the quotient.)

Comment: @AllenKnutson, I see, thank you. So we can think of X as the "Klein Bottle", and if $j=0$, the range of the maps is $S^4$, if $j=1$ the range is a closed 4-dim disc embedded in $\mathbb{R}^5$, if $j=4$ I think we get a 1-dim line in $\mathbb{R}^5$. Does that make sense? Not sure about the other cases. At any rate, how do you then go about classifying those maps under regular homotopy? How do you relate $\pi_2(Y)\equiv\pi_{S^2}(Y)$ for some $Y$ to $\pi_{Klein}(Y)$?